# reverse proxy using nginx container TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: docker, nginx

I am using xibo-cms with docker and I would like to set an nginx proxy server for ssl purposes I created a docker-compose file with all containers but I always got error TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS when I set `proxy_set_header   Host $host;` parameter without the parameter the url is redirected to the container service name which is unknown by the browser. I didn't understand what is wrong with my configuration.

my docker compose

```
version: "2.1"

services:
    proxy:
        image: nginx:1.23.2-alpine
        volumes:
          - ./conf/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
          - /etc/ssl/certs/STAR_mydomain.com.pem:/etc/ssl/certs/STAR_mydomain.com.pem
        ports:
          - "443:443"
          - "80:80"
        restart: always
    cms-db:
        image: mysql:5.7
        volumes:
            - "./shared/db:/var/lib/mysql:Z"
        environment:
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=cms
            - MYSQL_USER=cms
            - MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=yes
        mem_limit: 1g
        env_file: config.env
        restart: always
    cms-xmr:
        image: xibosignage/xibo-xmr:0.9
        ports:
            - "9505:9505"
        restart: always
        mem_limit: 256m
        env_file: config.env
    cms-web:
        image: xibosignage/xibo-cms:release-3.2.1
        volumes:
            - "./shared/cms/custom:/var/www/cms/custom:Z"
            - "./shared/backup:/var/www/backup:Z"
            - "./shared/cms/web/theme/custom:/var/www/cms/web/theme/custom:Z"
            - "./shared/cms/library:/var/www/cms/library:Z"
            - "./shared/cms/web/userscripts:/var/www/cms/web/userscripts:Z"
            - "./shared/cms/ca-certs:/var/www/cms/ca-certs:Z"
        restart: always
        links:
            - cms-db:mysql
            - cms-xmr:50001
            - proxy
        environment:
            - XMR_HOST=cms-xmr
            - CMS_USE_MEMCACHED=true
            - MEMCACHED_HOST=cms-memcached
        env_file: config.env
#        ports:
#            - "8080:80"
        mem_limit: 1g
    cms-memcached:
        image: memcached:alpine
        command: memcached -m 15
        restart: always
        mem_limit: 100M
    cms-quickchart:
      image: ianw/quickchart
      restart: always
```

and here is my nginx config

```
    upstream docker-xibo {
        server xiboo-cms-web-1:80;
    }

   server {
     if ($host = display.mydomain.com) {
       return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

     listen 80;
      server_name display.mydomain.com;
  }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name display.mydomain.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/STAR_mydomain.com.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/STAR_mydomain.com.pem;


        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://docker-xibo;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: `if ($host = display.mydomain.com) { return 301 https://$host$request_uri; }` is an endless loop..... Note that webserver configuration is off topic on SO. use `https://superuser.com`

Comment: Thank you, I was suspecting the ssl redirect. So I have to hard code the destination URL here! Thank you.

Comment: Even with https://display.mydomain.com I got the same error

Comment: See the two last sentences of my above comment.

Comment: I understood that the webserver config is off topic, The web server works fine, I just don't understand what is messed up for having the redirection error

Comment: .... which is a webserver configuration issue which is off-topic.

Comment: and you are right :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on the backend which have configured with https connection nginx proxy configuration was right.